# Data query for beta sites?

Tags: discussion, beta, data-explorer

Recently I discovered the "Data" link at the bottom of the SE sites.  It's a very cool tool.  I also noticed that Programmers.SE is not in the list of sites that can be queried.

Is it safe to assume that the "Data" link is for all NON-beta sites?

Comment: I think so, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No beta sites are accessible with Data Explorer, only finished sites and their beta's. I'm working on a scraper to reconstruct as much of the DB as I can, but it will take some time before I get a release.